# How to delete user on logout and when session expires?

Tags: users

I am looking for a way to delete a user when they logout and when session expires...whatever one happens first?
Reason being is that all login authentication happens through an api to another company and checks if the user is a registered user with that company. Then the login will give them WP login authentication. All of this works, but I now want to delete users when they log out or when their session expires.
Thanks.

Comment: Your best chance is probably using the `wp_clear_auth_cookie` action hook.
As for logout - you do have a hook at `wp_logout()`.. but the only thing it does is later call  `wp_clear_auth_cookie()` again...  Anyhow, you would have to make own-user controls - otherwise , ALL users will be always deleted ( including ADMINS ). I would go for only a specific or even custom user-level/type. Do you want it for ALL users, or only spedific login-redirections ones

Comment: @krembo99 As an answer.

Comment: When the users are created they are given a special meta-key/value with the user level and client id from the third party. I can use the meta key to target and delete the users.  I will look at the wp_clear_auth_cookie and get back to you. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

So this is what I did...also keep in mind this is for a multisite and I am call calling this within a class. 'Client' is a custom user role that is create and given to users when they are created.

```
   function delete_user() {
        global $current_user;

        if(in_array('client', $current_user->roles )){
            if(!function_exists('wp_delete_user')) {

                include(ABSPATH . "wp-admin/includes/ms.php");
            }
            wpmu_delete_user( $current_user->ID );
        }
    }
add_action('clear_auth_cookie', 'delete_user');
```

I do have one question...this works when the user logs out, but when will it run on its own. When the cookie times out?

Answer (score 0):

there you have mistake, you should have:

```
        .........
        if(!function_exists('wp_delete_user'))  {  include(ABSPATH . "wp-admin/includes/user.php");  }
        if(!function_exists('wpmu_delete_user')){  include(ABSPATH . "wp-admin/includes/ms.php");  }
        wpmu_delete_user( $current_user->ID );
        ..........
```

Answer (score 0):

I think first you have to update a meta before user makes logout. 
There will be a function that will run in init hook which will check for the meta value.
If that meta value is present then it will remov the user whose id has that meta key value pair.

```
function users_last_login() {
    $userinfo = wp_get_current_user();
    update_user_meta( $userinfo->ID, 'last_action', 'logout' );
}
add_action('clear_auth_cookie', 'users_last_login', 10);
add_action('init', 'delete_users' );

function delete_users() {
  $users = get_users(
            array(
              'meta_key' => 'last_action',
              'meta_value' => 'logout',
            ) 
          );
  if( !empty($users) ) {
    foreach( $users as $user ) {
      wp_delete_user($user->data->ID);
    }
  }
}
```